# How can i made soap Request and Response in Java?

Tags: java, web-services, soap

How can I execute the soap webservices and how can I print the data?

Currently I am using the following code

```
package com.appulento.pack;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class SimpleHTTPRequest
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String url =
        "http://**********:8000/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zmaterials_details/" +
          "800/zmaterials_details/zmaterials_details_bind",
      soapAction ="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style/ZMATERIALS_DETAILS",
      envelope1="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
        "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"" +
          " xmlns:urn=\"urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style\">" +
        "<soapenv:Header>"+
        "<soapenv:Body>"+
        "<urn:ZMATERIALS_DETAILS>"+
        "<Language>D</Language>"+
        "<MaterialGroup>00208</MaterialGroup>"+
        "</urn:ZMATERIALS_DETAILS>"+
        "</soap:Body>"+
        "</soap:Envelope>" ;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
      final URL serverAddress = new URL("http://*********:8000/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/"+
          "srvc_14DAE9C8D79F1EE196F1FC6C6518A345/wsdl11/allinone/ws_policy/" +
          "document?sap-client=800&sap-user=************&sap-password=****");
      connection = (HttpURLConnection)serverAddress.openConnection();
      connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", soapAction);
      connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
      connection.setDoOutput(true);
      final OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
      writer.append(envelope1);
      writer.close();
      final BufferedReader rd =
          new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
      String line;
      while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) System.out.println(line);
    } finally { connection.disconnect(); }
  }
}
```

I want send xml as input request and I want to display in xml too.

Comment: Your code looks fantastic. Now just use `POST` instead of `GET` and actually write your request into the output.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply how can i handle the response

Comment: As far as I can see, you're already handling it -- writing to the System.out.

Comment: HERE I AM ONLY GETTING THE WSDL IN CONSOLE

Comment: plese check once where i am doing mistake in my code

Comment: how can i print that output in xml ....

Comment: Update your code here according to my instructions above. Then we can talk further.

Comment: i updated my code please see once...

Comment: You managed to change GET to POST. Now follow the rest of my intstruction.

Comment: i am new to web services how can i write the output on the screen

Comment: You're not writing anything to that `writer`. You are not sending your request string to the service.

Comment: i am  struck over here how can i made request through writer ?

Comment: You have your request string. You have your writer. Did you try reading the Javadoc on that writer? It's quite clear how to write a string to a writer.

Comment: please guide me how can i made request thanks for ur help

Comment: wr.write("POST " + serverAddress + " HTTP/1.0\r\n");
           wr.write("Host: ************\r\n");
           wr.write("Content-Length: " + envelope1.length() + "\r\n");
           wr.write("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n");
           wr.write("\r\n");

Comment: i am writting like this correct or please let me know ?

Comment: No. `HttpUrlConnection` takes care of the headers. If you need to set them, use its API. Just write your request into the writer (it's there in your local var `envelope1`, as far as I can see).

Comment: ok thanks is it correct   writer.append(envelope1);

Comment: As correct as using `write` that you already used. Don't forget to `close` the writer when done writing.

Comment: ok thanks for ur reply now how can i see response from webservices after that services exicuted ?

Comment: but now i am not getting any output in my console i am just see the wsdl data?

Comment: see once i am updated my latest code

Comment: please tel me where can i doing mistake when i displaying the result in The console

Comment: I edited your code. I told you to close the writer when done writing, but you didn't. You closed it in the end. You cannot start reading the response before you are done sending the request!

Comment: writer.append(envelope1);
 writer.close(); i am putting the like this but i cannot see any response in my console

Comment: wsdl data is printing in my console

Comment: after putting your edited code i don't see any data  on Console  thanks for ur work

Comment: please see once Marko i am struck over here from Long Time

Comment: I hope you realize that it is not true that you don't see the response, you see it very well -- it's the WSDL. The service is sending back WSDL instead of performing your request. Find out why it does that. Maybe the URL is not quite right, maybe there's something more you must put in a header. I don't know all the details.

Comment: my input xml as <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:urn="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <urn:ZMATERIALS_DETAILS>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <Language>D</Language>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <MaterialGroup>00208</MaterialGroup>
      </urn:ZMATERIALS_DETAILS>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Comment: see once my input xml it is working in SOPAUI pro

Comment: I didn't mention your xml as source of trouble. It isn't. I gave you two other possibilities, though. Why don't you start a network sniffer like WireShark, or maybe get SoapUI to print out the exact contents of its request?

Comment: i tested in Soap Ui it showing result fine ?

Comment: i changed another web services with another input XML the output is wsdl Data of the webservices..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iit's possible to sent HTTP request using httpConnection and parse response, like you do. 
But it is already written by other people, use `wsimport` tool with `-keep` option. It will generate for you Java artifacts for sending request using SOAP.

Comment: is there any mistake in My Code please see once and let me know so that i can move to other way of doing